# Examples of interesting cones in infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, convex-cone

Let $X$ be a real Hilbert space, and let $K$ be a closed convex cone.

The *dual* cone is defined by $K^*=\{x^*\in X \mid (\forall k\in K)\, \langle x^*,k\rangle \geq 0 \}$.

I am looking for some interesting examples of $K$ and $K^*$, especially when $X$ is infinite-dimensional.

For example,

- $X=\ell_2$ and $K=\ell_2^+ = K^*$
- $X=L_2[0,1]$ and $K=L_2^+[0,1]=K^*$

Note that these examples satisfy $K-K=X$. I wonder if there are some concrete examples where

$$K-K\neq X\quad \text{but}\quad \overline{K-K}=X$$

and $K^*$ is actually known?

Any examples/comments/references would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let us take the Sobolev space $X = H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $K = X^+ = \{ v \in H_0^1(\Omega) \mid v \ge 0 \text{ a.e.}\}$. Then, we have $X = K - K$.
Note that $X$ is a Hilbert space.

However, the dual cone $K^*$ coincides with the non-negative functionals in $H^{-1}(\Omega) = X^*$. This are precisely the functionals in $X^*$ which can be represented by measures which are finite on compact sets,
i.e., for each $\mu \in K^*$, there is a measure $\hat\mu$ such that
$$
\langle \mu, v\rangle = \int_\Omega v \, \mathrm{d}\hat\mu\qquad \forall \mu \in H_0^1(\Omega) \cap C_c(\Omega).$$

Now, one can check that we have $X^* = \overline{K^* - K^*} \ne K^* - K^*$, see also
[Decomposition of functionals on sobolev spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336834/decomposition-of-functionals-on-sobolev-spaces)
and
[Decomposition of measures acting on sobolev spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1402697/decomposition-of-measures-acting-on-sobolev-spaces).

Comment: Thanks! Can you add some details on whether X is a Hilbert space here? A reference would be great.

Comment: Yes $X$ is a Hilbert space, I have added this information and I also added that $X$ is called a Sobolev space. As reference, you can take any book on Sobolev spaces.

Comment: Any favourite reference easily accessible to outsiders, gerw? Also, you say that $X^*=H^{-1}(\Omega)$. But $X^*=X$ for a Hilbert space - what am I missing?

Comment: Maybe "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations" by Brezis; in German there is also "Lineare Funktionalanalysis" by Alt. In $X^* = H^{-1}(\Omega)$ (and similar statements), the "=" is actually a "is isometrically isomorphic"; and all separable Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic. For function spaces, one typically does not use the isomorphism which makes $X = X^*$, since this involves the inner product and this depends on the space. For example, we still identify $L^2(\Omega)^* = L^2(\Omega)$, but not $H^1(\Omega)$ and its dual.